# how to exit from console application and close the window in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

I have given user an option to select an option for exit in console application in c#
I tried in that keypress:

Environment.Exit(0);

but the screen remains open

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should go to the bottom of your application and exit.

```
return;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your application uses threads, it's possible that there's a thread running in the background that keeps the application from closing. If that's the case, you may want to set that thread's [`IsBackground` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) to true. This will allow the application to close even if the thread is still running.

From the above link:

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.